# Regarding installation of PRI card into the Linux Machine to use with Asterisk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asterisk, telephony

I have installed Asterisk along with `Libpri` and `DAHDI` into my Ubuntu machine and i am able to run my asterisk Server nicely.Now as per my requirement i need to add the PRI card into `PCI Express`  of my System.So after adding PRI card into PCI Express ,What settings do i need to do to enable it.I mean how i need to configure this Card to work with Asterisk?

Also what necessary settings i need to do in asterisk to make the Inbound as well outbound calls happen in my Asterisk.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With dahdi this work is very easy.

First run:

```
dahdi_genconf
```

This command will generate this file /etc/dahdi/system.conf

And they look like this:

```
# Span 1: WCT1/0 "Digium Wildcard TE110P T1/E1 Card 0" (MASTER) 
span=1,1,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=1-15,17-31
dchan=16
echocanceller=oslec,1-15,17-31
```

You need to set some parameters according to your provider. See more info here: 
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/system.conf

In second place, add this lines to your /etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf

```
; Span 1: WCT1/0 "Digium Wildcard TE110P T1/E1 Card 0" (MASTER) 
group=1
context=from-pstn
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = pri_cpe
channel => 1-15,17-21
context = default
```

Here you'll found an example:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/chan_dahdi.conf

Regards